# Embed Facebook post without Firefox trackers blocking

Tags: node.js, facebook, firefox, iframe, embed

How to embed last Facebook post (and its media) in a page without any bloking security issue (while being design responsive) ?

---

My client ask me to embed her last Facebook post on her front page. A previous solution was to use an iframe as following:
`html
 <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fusername%2Fposts%2F<%- fb_post_id %>&width=750" width="750" height="350" style="border:none" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe> </div>`

In addition to be an inelegant not responsive solution, the content is blocked on Firefox probably due to FB trackers.
The current idea is to grab as much content I can with `fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/username/posts?limit=1&access_token=" + token)` *on the NodeJs server* and mock Facebook post design by hand. The main issue is that I don't have access to post's media (picture, linked FB posts, video...) just post's text.

(I am using NodeJs 10, express and ejs)

Comment: Why would this be blocked as mixed content - it is requested via HTTPS already (and I doubt Facebook messes this up and then embeds HTTP resources inside.) More likely this is blocked due to Firefox’s _privacy_ settings. They started blocking a lot of social media stuff and content that does not respect Do-Not-Track by default a while ago.

Comment: _“The main issue is that I don't have access to post's media (picture, linked FB posts, video...) just post's text.”_ - that’s because you are not _asking_ for any additional fields with that request, so you just get a few default ones returned. How to ask for additional fields, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Comment: @misorude yeah I wasn't sure that trackers and mix-content wasn't related as I was systematically redirected to Firefox mix-content blocking article when I searched for a workaround. Definitively trackers. I edited my original post. Thanks. But how to get away from trackers?

Comment: Well how about respecting user’s choices in that regard, that would be a novel approach :-) If that’s not an option, then you will have to go via API, fetch the content, and display it yourself somehow.

Comment: @misorude In that case, that would be counting on (1) each single visitor (2) to unblock Facebook trackers (3) on the page. IMO, that doesn't make any sense neither for my client(1), for me as a dev (2), and the final user (3). Nobody asked for these trackers... So I will build a mockup of FB post with server side fetched content thanks to your remark on my call of the API. Is there an official way to detect Firefox blocked content or is empty iframe test my solely solace?